# Typescript: onPress type

Tags: typescript, react-native

I just ported my react-native project to typescript and have a question about functions as props

im passing:

```
<DisplayCardsWithLikes
data={testData}
likes={500}
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("CardDetailScreen")}
/>
```

to

```
type Props = {
  onPress: Function
}


const FloatingActionButtonSimple = (props:Props) => {
  const {onPress} = props
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerFab}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.fab} onPress={onPress}>
        <Icon name="plus" size={16} color={"white"} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Error:

```
Error, caused by child onPress:
o overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps>): TouchableOpacity', gave the following error.
    Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(event: GestureResponderEvent) => void'.
      Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(event: GestureResponderEvent): void'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: TouchableOpacityProps, context?: any): TouchableOpacity', gave the following error.
    Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(event: GestureResponderEvent) => void'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(5125, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onPress' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableOpacity> & Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps> & Readonly<...>'
index.d.ts(5125, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onPress' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TouchableOpacity> & Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps> & Readonly<...>'
```

Summary:
onPress passed as prop (is a function). On child type onPress:Function displays an error(the one above), onPress:any works though. I basically don't know which kind of type the onPress prop is

So nothing crazy, but if I define onPress as a function it displays an error, so apparently that's not the correct type. Do you know which type this onPress functions are?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the error? And which line of code is that error coming from?

Comment: Hey Alex, i tried to make it more clear: I want to give the onPress method a type, but if I set it to function it displays an error, on any it works. So i don't know which type to assign onPress to

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to define type as below to get rid of type error from tslint:

```js
type Props {
   onPress: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void
}
```

OR

```js
type Props {
   onPress(): void
}
```

OR

```js
type Props {
   onPress(params: type): void
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For everyone looking Alex Wahne provided the perfect explantion.

Comment: Can you explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 12):

That error message shows the type that it would accept for your function as this:

```
(event: GestureResponderEvent) => void
```

What's important to note is `=> void` which means it's expecting a function that does *not* return a value.

But this function:

```
() => this.props.navigation.navigate("CardDetailScreen")
```

*does* return a value. Arrow function's without `{}`'s return the result of their expression.

The fix is to add `{}` to your callback so the function does not return anything, which will match the expected type:

```
onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate("CardDetailScreen") } }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex for the explanation! Unfortunately the supposed solution does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { GestureResponderEvent } from "react-native";
```

I imported GestureResponderEvent from React Native and then used that as my event type:

```
  async function submit(e: GestureResponderEvent) {
```

here's the onPress code:

```
  <Pressable onPress={submit}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   In my case declaring it  the type as 
    
    type Props {
       onPress: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void
    }

    did not work for me. What worked for me is declaring an interface as below and call it in my code.
    
    interface Props {
      title: string;
      onPress?: Function;
    }
   
    
    <Button
          onPress={handleSubmit as (e?: GestureResponderEvent) => void}
          title={props.title}
        />
```

You will need to import GestureResponderEvent from react-native as below

import {GestureResponderEvent} from 'react-native';

screenshot of my errors attached [image]

Hope it helps someone.